# Nuxt Deploy on Plesk

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, plesk

I need to deploy my Nuxt App on Plesk.

I set "/httpdocs/nuxt-app" in Document Root,
and "/httpdocs/nuxt-app" in Application Root

nuxt-app contains all files and folders as .output,.nuxt, package.json

```
   Vue packages version mismatch:
   - vue@3.2.45
   - vue-server-renderer@2.7.14
```

Comment: Plesk has nothing to do with that error. Solve the incompatibility issues within your `package.json`. Check [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+packages+version+mismatch) or make a search on the website, this issue is quite frequent.

Comment: do you wana deploy nuxt2 or nuxt3?

Comment: I'm deploying on Nuxt 3

Comment: My comment still stands so.